"He's one of the people who doesn't/don't eat lunch." Which is correct?
"He's one of the few people who doesn't eat lunch."
"He's one of the few people who don't eat lunch."
Which is correct?

Doesn't is a contraction of Does not. The word don't is a contraction of do not. Just place those into the sentence and you will be able to make a better choice.

The second one. Test: Of the few people who don’t eat lunch, he’s one.

In this case, 'one of the few people who' essentially forces 'don't' as 'few people' must apply to this {lunchless} subset. But 'He's one of the people who Ø eat lunch' is indeterminate. See He is one of the boys who play or plays football, one of the children who was vs one of the children who were etc. and note the different meanings

Your question shows no research. Moreover, it has already been asked and answered on this site many, many, many, many, many times already.

Q: What is he one of?
A: The people who don’t eat lunch.

Thank you! I was lost about whether or not I should match the verb to "one" or the plural.

Related question - is it always third person singular for "someone" then? For example, "you're someone who isn't even supposed to be here" and "I'm someone who is always late" Are both correct?

These too could serve as answers, in this case, to What am I? and What are you?, respectively. Or even What am I [or you] one of? In both cases, the who is… phrases complement the singular noun someone. And complement means make whole or fill out.

You are trying to rationalise the language in a way that the language blankly refuses to recognise!

@Araucaria-Him, I freely agree that language refuses to comply completely with rigorous grammars (in the mathematical or computer-science sense of the term grammar). But in this case and in my experience, most native speakers’ usage is accurately described by my explanation immediately above. But certainly, very very few speakers perform (or would be able to generate) the analysis I offered.

See my answer above!

Yeah, @Araucaria-Him, I had thought of your meaning B, but decided to (implicitly) make the (simplifying) bet that meaning A was OP’s intention.

@PaulTanenbaum Yes, but what CaGEL point out is that either singular or plural verb agreement can be used to convey meaning A!

That it does get used that way, I do not dispute, @Araucaria-Him. And that it is correct to use it that way depends on one’s conception of correctness. In any event, if my version relies on a rationalisation, then theirs certainly does too. And one that is even more abstruse than mine :-). In any event, when I hear one of the people who am, my brain by default creates interpretation B.

Short answer
Either sentence is fine. The notional Subject of the auxiliary verb DO is the plural noun phrase the people. However, in English the word one which occurs earlier in the larger noun phrase can optionally override the expected subject-verb agreement in the relative clause causing a singular verb form.
Full answer


He is [one of the few people who doesn't eat lunch].
He is [one of the few people who don't eat lunch].


Based solely on the grammar there are two possible readings of these sentences:

A: There is a small group of people that doesn't eat lunch. He is a member of that group

B: He is a member of a group of people. He doesn't eat lunch.


Common sense tells us that the writer wants to convey meaning A, and not meaning B. We could model the larger noun phrases like this according to their meaning:

A: One of [the people who don't eat lunch]
B: One of [the people] who doesn't eat lunch.

Here we can see that with meaning A, the notional Subject of the verb DO is the plural noun phrase the people. In B, the notional Subject of the verb DO is the singular noun phrase one of the few people.
Now it would be nice, wouldn't it, if sentence (1) always meant A, and sentence (2) always meant B. However, that's not the case. The fact is that native speakers, both in speech and writing, often use sentences like (2) to express meanings like A. The reason is that the word one often overrides normal verb agreement. In other words although sentence (1) definitely expresses A, sentence (2) would be used to express either A or B.
Here is what a vetted grammar source, based on real data, the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language has to say about this:

. . . The relativized element in these examples is object. Where it is the subject that is relativized, the expectation would be that the number of the verb would be determined by the antecedent, giving a plural verb in Type I, and a singular in Type II. In practice, however, singular verbs are often found as alternants of plurals in Type I:
[22]

i. He's [one of those people who always want to have the last word]. -- (Type I )

ii. He's [one of those people who always wants to have the last word]. -- (Type I )

iii. He's [one of her colleagues who is always ready to criticize her]. -- (Type II )


Examples [i] and [iii] follow the ordinary rules, but [ii] involves a singular override. It can presumably be attributed to the salience within the whole structure of one and to the influence of the Type II structure (it is in effect a blend between Types I and II ). But it cannot be regarded as a semantically motivated override: semantically the relative clause modifies people. This singular override is most common when the relative clause follows those or those + noun.

In this kind of situation, thinking about the grammar is not the most useful guide. Even working out what the grammar is will take you quite some time. Go with your intuition!
Grammar note:
You may well be wondering why I used the term notional Subject instead of just Subject. The reason is that both of these noun phrases occur outside of the exist clause. They are potential antecedents for the Subject of the relative clause, but they do not occur within the relative clause itself.
References:
The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, Huddleston & Pullum [et al], 2002.

I appreciate that you answered, however your copy&paste has left the need for some edits to be made and I really didn't understand your answer because of them

Short memory?

@TheReturningDog Could you tell me where the edits need to be made, please? I've looked but I can't see them.

It doesn’t work both ways with the OP’s example. Test: ? Of the few people, he’s one who doesn’t eat lunch. Which few people?

Also, I think OP is referring to this out-of-place cut-and-paste: "Here we can see that with meaning A, the notional Subject of the verb exist is the plural noun phrase the most crucial problems. In B, the notional Subject of the verb exist is the singular noun phrase one of the most crucial problems."

@TinfoilHat Re first comment: That's a bit of a weird way to look at an example, no? One just assumes there's a context around the sentence involved.  Just like there would be for "He bit into the biscuit", for example. Re your second comment: thank you very much. My eye was refusing to engage with my brain there. Just couldn't see it.

@TheReturningDog Have edited. That should be better, I think.
